# DataTable - limit view by customer ID in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I am trying to fix an issue with a client.

He have an application which runs on the Codeigniter framework.
In this app, he is viewing a list of assignments via DataTables.

In the app, there exist three different access levels: Admin = 1, Employee = 2, Customer = 3

I am trying to limit the assignment list, to only show assignments belonging to the individual customer. I have tried to add the functionality in the controller for the assignment list, but it won't work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public function assignlist( $status = "" ){
    $status1 = "Aktiv";
    if($status!=""){
        $status1 = $status; 
    }
    /* by Kenn */
    $log_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $roleid = $log_in["role_id"];
    $CustomerID = $log_in["CustomerID"];
    /**/

    $this->datatables->select('er.EventId,er.EventName,cu.CustomerName as CustomerId,DATE_FORMAT(er.EventDate, "%d/%m/%Y") AS EventDate,er.TimeFrom,er.TimeTo,er.NoofGuardRequired,er.Remarks,emp.fullname as InsertBy,emp1.fullname as ModifiedBy,er.Status,er.Status as st,cu12.CustomerName as cuInsertBy, cu1.CustomerName as cuModifiedBy');
    $this->datatables->from('eventregistration er'); 
    $this->datatables->join('customer cu', 'cu.CustomerId = er.CustomerId', 'left');
    $this->datatables->join('employee emp', 'emp.emp_id = er.InsertBy', 'left');
    $this->datatables->join('employee emp1', 'emp1.emp_id = er.ModifiedBy', 'left');

    $this->datatables->join('customer cu12', 'cu12.CustomerId = er.InsertBy', 'left');
    $this->datatables->join('customer cu1', 'cu1.CustomerId = er.ModifiedBy', 'left');

    $this->datatables->where('er.Status',$status1);
    /* by Kenn */
    if ($roleid == "3"){
        $this->datatables->where('cu.CustomerID',$CustomerID);
    }
    /**/
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove multiple join on same table may fix your issue.

```
public function assignlist( $status = "" ){
    $status1 = "Aktiv";
    if($status!=""){
        $status1 = $status; 
    }
    /* by Kenn */
    $log_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $roleid = $log_in["role_id"];
    $CustomerID = $log_in["CustomerID"];
    /**/

    $this->datatables->select('er.EventId,er.EventName,cu.CustomerName as CustomerId,DATE_FORMAT(er.EventDate, "%d/%m/%Y") AS EventDate,er.TimeFrom,er.TimeTo,er.NoofGuardRequired,er.Remarks,emp.fullname as InsertBy,emp.fullname as ModifiedBy,er.Status,er.Status as st,cu.CustomerName as cuInsertBy, cu.CustomerName as cuModifiedBy');
    $this->datatables->from('eventregistration er'); 
    $this->datatables->join('customer cu', 'cu.CustomerId = er.CustomerId AND cu.CustomerId = er.InsertBy AND cu.CustomerId = er.ModifiedBy', 'left');
    $this->datatables->join('employee emp', 'emp.emp_id = er.InsertBy AND emp.emp_id = er.ModifiedBy', 'left');

    $this->datatables->where('er.Status',$status1);
    /* by Kenn */
    if ($roleid == "3"){
        $this->datatables->where('cu.CustomerID',$CustomerID);
    }
    /**/
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I just tried it, but it did not do the trick.
My code result in DataTable to write "No data available in table".

Comment: Fun part is, if I force to view e.g. CustomerID = 21, it works:
`if ($roleid == "3"){ $this->datatables->where('cu.CustomerID', "21");}`
It's like the variable store the customer ID differently?

Comment: You should write `$this->datatables->where('cu.CustomerId', "21");`  not `$this->datatables->where('cu.CustomerID', "21");` . Please replace `cu.CustomerID` with `cu.CustomerId` because `cu.CustomerID` and `cu.CustomerId` are two different things

Comment: just as I posted as an answer yesterday! :) But thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully found and fixed the bug. I suppose it was an error 40!

I review all characters incl. case-sensitivity and found the CustomerID should be CustomerId when I fetch the value from the array.

```
public function assignlist( $status = "" ){
    $status1 = "Aktiv";
    if($status!=""){
        $status1 = $status; 
    }
    /* by Kenn */
    $log_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $roleid = $log_in["role_id"];
    $CustomerId = $log_in["CustomerId"];
    /**/

    $this->datatables->select('er.EventId,er.EventName,cu.CustomerName as CustomerId,DATE_FORMAT(er.EventDate, "%d/%m/%Y") AS EventDate,er.TimeFrom,er.TimeTo,er.NoofGuardRequired,er.Remarks,emp.fullname as InsertBy,emp.fullname as ModifiedBy,er.Status,er.Status as st,cu.CustomerName as cuInsertBy, cu.CustomerName as cuModifiedBy');
    $this->datatables->from('eventregistration er'); 
    $this->datatables->join('customer cu', 'cu.CustomerId = er.CustomerId AND cu.CustomerId = er.InsertBy AND cu.CustomerId = er.ModifiedBy', 'left');
    $this->datatables->join('employee emp', 'emp.emp_id = er.InsertBy AND emp.emp_id = er.ModifiedBy', 'left');

    $this->datatables->where('er.Status',$status1);
    /* by Kenn */
    if ($roleid == "3"){
        $this->datatables->where('cu.CustomerId',$CustomerId);
    }
    /**/
    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
```